# Office 2016 share button IdMso

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, excel-addins, word-addins, office-2016

I'm trying to disable the new share button on the top right corner of the Office 2016 apps.

Does anyone know the correspondent IdMso? I've tried to locate the IdMso tables but I only find tables for the previous versions of Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has published the IDs for Office 2016 here:

> **[Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)**

As far as I can see, however, the *Share* button at the top left is not part of the Ribbon, i.e. you cannot remove it using a custom Ribbon XML (you can easily check this by providing a Ribbon XML which [resets everything](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd907088(v=office.12).aspx)).

In case that you don't know the ID of a control, there is also a simple way to retrieve it inside Office: Go to *File > Options > Customize Ribbon* and hover over the respective command or group:

**Command:**

[image]

**Group:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's unfortunate that we're not able to disable it :\ Thanks for the tip to get the Ids ;)

Meanwhile we are able to prevent the action afterwards on the save action.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late to the party, but since there's a way to at least disable the button in question, I'd like to share my findings after a [TechNet forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/05b66707-e67d-4b42-b363-096efd1b90f6/disable-quotsharequot-button-in-office-2016).

While there's a GPO (group policy object) way, I opted for the quicker way of adding the registry key myself:

1. Open the registry editor.
2. Since there's no single "Disable Share button" setting, you've got to create the node path `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\<OfficeApp>\DisabledCmdBarItemsList` & replace `<OfficeApp>` for each Office application you want the button being disabled in its Ribbon, i. e.

- `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\DisabledCmdBarItemsList` for Excel
- `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\DisabledCmdBarItemsList` for Word
- ...

3. In each created node path, add a `String value` named `TCID1`.
   3.1. In case there's already such an entry, increase the index at the end appropriately.
4. Set the newly created `String value` actual value to `26594`.
5. (Re-)Start the configured Office application to see the button awesomely disabled.

**Bonus for privacy lovers:**
While you're already within the registry editor, you can get rid of the `Sign In` button like this (courtesy of [another TechNet forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d9040af7-6054-4167-9b17-ca9d322e8cd1/remove-sign-in-box-from-office-apps)):

1. Go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\SignIn`.
2. Create a `DWORD value` named `SignInOptions`.
3. Set its value to `3`.
   3.1. For the curious: according to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/jj715259(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#signinoptions-settings), these are the value meanings:

- 0 = sign in via MS your organization's account
- 1 = MS account only
- 2 = organization's account only
  sers can sign in only by using the user ID that is assigned by your organization. This - 3 = Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) on Windows Server only
- 4 = no sign in with *any* ID allowed

4. (Re-)Start the configured Office application to see the button awesomely gone.