# Opening Power Query editor programmatically

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm improving my own tools for preparing corporate reports in Excel.

Current exercise: to reduce clicks count related to Power Query editor opening.

Current regular scenario once it needs to change existing query (see screenshot; sorry for non-EN locale in it)

- A. Go to ribbon menu "Data"
- B. Click "Book queries"
- C. In "Book queries" pane select relevant query
- D. Do double-click on it

Target/preferred scenario:

- 1. Do right-click on smart-table [assosiated with power query]
- 2. Click on my(custom) context menu item for opening Power Query editor

For now:

- I know how to add my(custom) context menu item, available only over the smart-table
- I know how to handle this menu item click in VBA
- ```
     check is it really clicked over the smart-table
  ```
- ```
     check/find associated query name
  ```

Problem: **I haven`t found any way how to start/open Power Query editor [for specific query] from VBA code [or what ever else].**

Thoughts:

- looks like Power Query editor is not available via Excel Application Object Model
- may be it would be available for automation via Commands("...") collection ?
- may be it has representation in VSTO via C# ?
- other ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could parameterise your existing power query so you never need to change it

Comment: If possible, what will you do next? You can put a command button on QAT to run PQ. I think it would be the shortest effort to run it.

Comment: BTW now I saw the button on your QAT (image).

Comment: @ALeXceL, haven't found command "Power Query editor" in list for QAT (Excel 2016). Would  you show how it looks like at your end?

_what will you do next?_
Ideally would like to have following VBA method =)
`sub openPowerQueryEditorFor(QueryName as String)`

Comment: @AndreyK It is the rightmost icon of the QAT displayed in the image you posted (spreadsheet with brush)

Comment: @ALeXceL, nope. There rightmost command icon is "Create style for Pivot Table".
If you mean "Customize QAT", then I tried it: looked frough the list of "All commands" and didn't find there something like "[open] Power Query [editor]". If you see such command, let me know ... or show a screenshot.

Comment: Mine is the same image: "Iniciar Editor do Power Query" in plain Pt-Br :-) See this image: [link](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSk_gufB-65zy17ocyiPL8ZqKK1FjmcTIQYE4czO1n6_9c1ZBtY3AiNvNFBxEi5EO3C6yE&usqp=CAU)

Comment: @AndreyK I don't have access to XL2016 frontend but in images on www there are the "Insert" Tab from where you probably get it. Mine is 32Bit XL365 Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ALeXceL for moving me to available option.

1. `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PowerQueryLaunchQueryEditor"`; see
   [about CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) and [how to identify idMso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387240/office-2016-share-button-idmso)
2. ONCE active/selected cell is inside smart table assosiated to query THEN editor opens on this query; thats why there is no "input parameter" like QueryName
3. Revised my "Target/preferred scenario"(from initial post); decided to use QAT+ShortCut as it was recommended in comments )